# Notice : Array to string conversion on array_intersect user meta

Tags: php, array, debug

I am trying to check if two meta data has any common array values. Its returning an error

**Notice: Array to string conversion in functions.php on line 1026** which is

```
$inbox = count(array_intersect($inmal, $newmails)) > 0 ? true : false;
```

The full code is here:

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$newmails = get_user_meta( $user->ID, '_user_mailbox_new', true );
$newmails = isset( $newmails ) && is_array($newmails) ? $newmails : array();
$mails = get_user_meta( $user->ID, '_user_mailbox', true );
$inmal = isset($mails['inbox']) && is_array($mails['inbox']) ? $mails['inbox'] : array();
$svmal = isset($mails['saved']) && is_array($mails['saved']) ? $mails['saved'] : array();
$inbox = count(array_intersect($inmal, $newmails)) > 0 ? true : false;
$saved = count(array_intersect($svmal, $newmails)) > 0 ? true : false;
```

I am getting the error for the last two lines. I am not getting why the error is there. Please help.

Comment: Are you sure that's the line 1026's code? Perhaps the problematic code is elsewhere.. because the code (in the question) seems working, though `$mails` should've been checked if it's an `array`, just like you did with the `$newmails`.

Comment: @SallyCJ Sorry for the late reply mate. Yes, that was indeed line 1026. The problem was with the `$mails['inbox']` array which I was assigning to `$inmal`. The `$mails['inbox']` was a multidimensional array and `$newmails` was an indexed array, hence the problem.